# How do I compute the Wronskian after finding the solution of an ODE that satisfies 2 initial conditions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the question, I was first given the following differential equation and was asked to compute the solution.

$$\frac {\mathrm{d}^{2}x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + 2\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + 5x = 0$$

After that, I found the solution satisfying the initial conditions $x(0) = 1$ and $x'(0) = 1$.

My solution was $x = e^{-t}\cos(2t) + e^{-t}\sin(2t)$.

But now I don't know how to compute the Wronskian from the solution.

If anybody could point me in the right direction that would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula for the Wronskian:
$$W=x_1x'_2-x_1'x_2$$
Where $x_1=e^{-t}\cos (2t)$ and
$x_2=e^{-t}\sin (2t)$.
Or you can easily solve :
$$W'=-2W$$
$$\implies (\ln W)'=-2$$

Answer (score 1):

Before you applied the initial conditions, you probably had a general solution like

$$ x(t) = c_1\exp(-t)\cos(2t) + c_2\exp(-t)\sin(2t) = c_1x_1(t) + c_2x_2(t) $$

The Wronskian is simply the determinant

$$W(t) = \begin{vmatrix} x_1(t) & x_2(t) \\ x_1'(t) & x_2'(t) \end{vmatrix} = x_1(t)x_2'(t) - x_1'(t)x_2(t) $$